# Experiencing difficulty testing an order using the 2Checkout payment gateway in PHP

Tags: php, 2checkout

I am trying to implement a 2checkout payment gateway. Currently, my account is in demo mode and as far as I know, there is no sandbox account. They have decommissioned it. For demo mode, it's showing an error message because my account is not active.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCYDJ.png)

Here is the code:

```
<form id="2checkout" action="https://www.2checkout.com/checkout/purchase" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="sid" value="254607497794"/>
<input type="hidden" name="mode" value="2CO"/>
<input type="hidden" name="li_0_name" value="Test Product"/>
<input type="hidden" name="li_0_price" value="0.01"/>
<input type='hidden' name='demo' value='Y' />
</form>

<input type="submit" value="Click here if you are not redirected automatically" /></form>
<script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById('2checkout').submit();</script>
```

Can you suggest to me how can I test it in demo mode and get rid of this error message?

Comment: This is an account issue with the service provider, not a programming issue we can help you with. We don't know how the account is set up, or even how it should be set up. You need to contact them and ask for some documentation or help.

Comment: I did that already but till now no solution was provided by them. Anyway, thanks.